# Do I need to connect the battery to send data to an ESP32 chip?

Tags: communication, esp8266

This may be a basic question, but I'm really new to electrical engineering.

I got an ESP32 chip with no micro-USB port. I got with the device a 3-Wire cable one side and USB other side. I have to connect these 3 wires respectively to TXD / RXD / Ground.

**So, to transfer data to my chip, do I must add a battery (connected to 3.3V and GND) to power it up ? Or just this 3-wires cable is enough ?**

Comment: It would help if you added a schematic.  But from what it sounds like you are doing, the TX and RX signals cannot power the module.  You need to have a 3.3V power supply in addition to what you explained.

Comment: An ESP module has electronics which need power. TXD and RXD are just **signals**, not power. GND is a common connection. You will also need to connect a power line like 3.3 V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need at least a battery or other DC power supply to power it up. You said you have a “chip” which sounds like just the ESP32 MCU without any supporting peripherals.  You will also need a crystal and some means of programming the ESP32 MCU.

Try searching for “esp32 minimal circuit”.  There’s a lot of existing info available.

For early stage prototyping, I would recommend getting a ESP32 dev board with USB so you have a working reference as a starting point, as they’re inexpensive and it will get you going faster with the basics, while you learn and prototype with the chip.